# Git CRLF LF EOL Conversion Setting

Tags: git, emacs, core.autocrlf

Platform: Windows 8.1 Emacs 24.3

The git config `--global -l` shows:

```
user.name=username
user.email=useremail
core.autocrlf=false
core.safecrlf=true
```

Git repository `.gitattributes` file:

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto

# Custom for Visual Studio
*.cs     diff=csharp
*.sln    merge=union
*.csproj merge=union
*.vbproj merge=union
*.fsproj merge=union
*.dbproj merge=union

# Standard to msysgit
*.doc    diff=astextplain
*.DOC    diff=astextplain
*.docx diff=astextplain
*.DOCX diff=astextplain
*.dot  diff=astextplain
*.DOT  diff=astextplain
*.pdf  diff=astextplain
*.PDF    diff=astextplain
*.rtf    diff=astextplain
*.RTF    diff=astextplain
```

I do think my Git and repository settings are right.

But everytime I create a new text file with Emacs, I cannot run `git add <newfile>`. The file is encoded by `utf-8-unix`.

The error message is as:

```
E:\workspace\repository [master +0 ~2 -0]> git add .
fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in newfile.txt
```

I don't think is due to emacs editor problem. Because I opened the new file and pretty sure the line ending is `LF` not the windows default `CRLF`.

Which configuration part decides LF will be replaced by CRLF?

---

***EDIT 1***
If `safecrlf` is set to `warn` the output is:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in _posts/2014-11-19-test.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

This means that the file was successfully added to the index. My file is encoded by `utf-8-unix`.

---

***EDIT 2***

Interestingly, if I create a new file with Notepad not the Emacs 24.3, the file can be added without any problem. The difference is Notepad adopts `CRLF` line ending while Emacs 24.3 adopts `LF` line ending.

So the problem is somewhere somehow Git converts `CRLF` to `LF` then back to `CRLF` which generates error for original `LF` line ending file.

---

***EDIT 3***

Previously, GitHub Windows GUI client warned me no `.gitattributes` file for my repository and recommend a default `.gitattributes` file as above.

I think the problem is from the line `* text=auto`. So I comment out this line.

Everything works good now!

---

***EDIT 4***

The core is:

- ***DISABLE AUTO LINE ENDING CONVERSION*** by GitHub.
- ***DEPEND ON PLATFORM FILE EDITOR FOR LINE ENDING***.

---

***EDIT 5***

1. `text`
   This attribute enables and controls end-of-line normalization. When a text file is normalized, its line endings are converted to `LF` **in the repository**. To control what line ending style is used **in the working directory**, use the `eol` attribute **for a single file** and the `core.eol` configuration variable **for all text files**.

   - Setting the `text` attribute on a path enables end-of-line normalization and marks the path as a text file. End-of-line conversion takes place **without guessing the content type**.
   - Unsetting the `text` attribute on a path tells Git **not to attempt any end-of-line conversion upon checkin or checkout**.
   - When `text` is set to "`auto`", the path is marked for automatic end-of-line normalization. If *Git decides that the content is text*, its line endings are normalized to **`LF` on checkin**.
   - Unspecified. If the `text` attribute is unspecified (by `!text` or no setting entry at all), Git uses the `core.autocrlf` configuration variable to determine if the file should be converted (fall-back compatibility as noted in ***EDIT 8***).
2. `eol`
   This attribute sets a specific line-ending style to be used in the working directory. It enables end-of-line normalization without any content checks, **effectively setting the `text` attribute**.

   - *That is to say `eol` automatically set `text` attribute*.
   - Set to string value "crlf"
     This setting forces Git to normalize line endings for this file on checkin and convert them to CRLF when the file is checked out.
   - Set to string value "lf"
     This setting forces Git to normalize line endings to LF on checkin and prevents conversion to CRLF when the file is checked out.

If `eol` is put in `.gitattributes` file, it should be applied to specific file type. At the same time, it automatically marks the specific file type as `text` at the same time for LF normalization when checkin. If `eol` is set as `git config --global core.eol xxx`, then `eol` is set for **all** text files.

Refer to [gitattributes - defining attributes per path](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

---

***EDIT 6***

Git attributes are specified in `.gitattributes` files. Line endings are controlled by `text` and `eol` attributes.

`text` attribute tells Git whether the file is `binary` (i.e. no `EOL` conversion should be performed while checking out and in) or `text` (perform `EOL` conversion, always convert to `LF` while checking in). Possible values are set (EOLs conversion is turned on), unset(EOLs conversion is turned off, default value) and `auto`(if the file is detected as binary, no conversion, otherwise EOLs conversion is performed).

`eol` attribute: if set implicitly sets `text` attribute and defines EOL to which the file should be converted while checking out.

Refer to [Line endings handling in SVN, Git and SubGit](http://blog.subgit.com/line-endings-handling-in-svn-git-and-subgit/)

---

***EDIT 7***

Possible solutions:

1. As ***EDIT 3***, comment out `* text=auto`
2. Add a line in `gitattributes` for `.md` file: `*.md eol=lf`

   - If another kind of text file such as `.txt` is created, I should also add a line for it `*.txt eol=lf`
3. Change `* text=auto` to `* !text`
4. Totally remove the `.gitattributes` file

To my current knowledge I think:

1. By `filetype text` in `gitattributes`, EOL normalization is carried out for `filetype` at checkin.
2. AT THE SAME TIME, this line implicates that `default eol` should also be carried out when checkout. `default` means depending on global configuration as `git config --global core.eol xxx` or default operating system style as `core.eol = native`.

   - You can run `git config --global core.eol` to see what this value is set to on your system. If nothing comes back that means you are on the using the OS default which is `native`.
3. **eol implicates `text` attribute, while `text` implicates default `eol` attribute**.
4. So when `*.md text=auto` is enabled. `*.md` file is detected by Git as `text` file and converted to LF when checkin. When checkout, `*.md` LF will be converted to CRLF. This process is invalidated by `safecrlf = false` global setting, refusing to adding the file to index/stage area.

---

***EDIT 8***

My three assumptions in ***EDIT 7*** is verified [**Mind the End of Your Line**](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)

Since Git 1.7.2 and above, EOL settings are mainly put in `.gitattributes` in the root directory of working tree. The global config `autocrlf` is only for fall-back compatibility.

`*.txt text` Set all files matching the filter `*.txt` to be `text`. This means that Git will run `CRLF` to `LF`replacement on these files every time they are written to the object database and **the reverse replacement will be run when writing out to the working directory**.

---

***EDIT 9 Final Idea***

1. `text` and `core.autocrlf`(in `.gitattributes`) focuses on EOL conversion writing to repository database from working tree.
2. `eol` and `core.eol`(in `global config`) focuses on EOL conversion writing to working tree from repository database.
3. `.gitattributes` has higher precedence than `global config` when deciding EOL conversion. The later one is actually fall-back reference.
4. If one way conversion is specified, the other way is unspecified or undefined, the default fall-back option is used for the other way conversion.
5. The EOL issue associates closely with which line ending you choose when editing files.

For logical explanation refer to my blog [**znhoo**](http://www.fangxiang.tk/2014/09/08/git-line-ending-conversion/)

Comment: Ah! `man gitattributes` says that `text=auto` "ensures that all files that Git considers to be text will have normalized (LF) line endings in the repository".

Comment: When you edit please don't write comments like 'EDIT' (or 'UPDATE') - every post has a revision history that shows what changed with every edit automatically, duplicating that gains nothing and makes the question look really weird to people reading it in the future (which is where most of the views will come from)

Comment: @Flexo What comments should I put there? Since each time I only change little bit. Not easy to describe.

Comment: To be honest it doesn't matter that much, something like 'adding the missing Foo', but the question works much better if you write it in a style that pretends you wrote it with all the information from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the `core.safecrlf=true` in your Git config.

From [the git-config manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

```
core.safecrlf
    If true, makes git check if converting CRLF is reversible when
    end-of-line conversion is active. Git will verify if a command
    modifies a file in the work tree either directly or indirectly. For
    example, committing a file followed by checking out the same file
    should yield the original file in the work tree. If this is not the
    case for the current setting of core.autocrlf, git will reject the
    file. The variable can be set to "warn", in which case git will only
    warn about an irreversible conversion but continue the operation.
```

Comment: 'when end of line converting is active' is the condition. I have set 'autocrlf' to be 'false'. So I don't think it is due to 'safecrlf'

Comment: Oh, you're right. Well, just for grins, what happens if you change safecrlf to false or warn?

Comment: The output is warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in _posts/new file.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. As ***EDIT 3***, comment out `* text=auto`
2. Add a line in `gitattributes` for `.md` file: `*.md eol=lf`

   - If another kind of text file such as `.txt` is created, I should also add a line for it `*.txt eol=lf`
3. Change `* text=auto` to `* !text`
4. Totally remove the `.gitattributes` file